# Backbone API fetch() from Model using API authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, backbone.js

I have problem with my Backbone mobile app (using Cordova, Require, Handlebars, etc..).
In particular the console log of chrome give me this result:
[image: Chrome Console LOG].

I've tried different solutions taken by debugging and searching on the web.

The **first** are defining the urlRoot in my Model.backbone and calling the function mymodel.fetch(). And the result given is: [image: Chrome Console LOG].

This is the code:

```js
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  constructorName: "MyModel",

  urlRoot: 'http://192.168.56.101/XXX/api/categories/26?io_format=JSON'
});
```

```js
myView: function() {


  var model = new MyModel();

  model.fetch();



  // create the view
  var page = new MyView({
    model: model
  });
  // show the view
  this.changePage(page);

},
```

The **second** solution is embedding the API KEY in the `urlRoot`. Like that:

```js
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  constructorName: "MyModel",

  urlRoot: 'http://IYI6M35MLB8UVW38fhj9RY3YPQWRX5X8H@192.168.56.101/XXX/api/categories/26?io_format=JSON'
});
```

The **last** solution that we tried was passing the header in the fetch call. Like this code:

```js
 myView: function() {


   var model = new MyModel();

   model.fetch({
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Basic IYI6M35MLB8UVW38Y99RrgsrPQWRX5X8H:'
     }
   });



   // create the view
   var page = new MyView({
     model: model
   });
   // show the view
   this.changePage(page);

 },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

All of this solutions give me the same result, like "Chrome Console LOG", he sad me "Unauthorized etc.." like the image.
Can you give me some help? How can I bring JSON object in a model in Backbone using API with authentication by Username?

Comment: This is a CORS issue. You are trying to access resources outside the domain of your application. Looks into the solutions for fixing cross origin policy.

Comment: as @TJ has mentioned, solve the CORS issue,  one way is to have both endpoints  behind the same reverse proxy, or setting appropriate headers.